# MVC Partial view appearing in another window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

If the user clicks on register the first time it opens up the popup window like it should. However if the user clicks on submit, it opens a new window, instead of staying on the same page and displaying the popup again.

How it should be:
[image]
What happens when user doesn't enter anything:
[image]

_Layout Code:

```
<section id="login">
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Register", "../Users/Register",
                                      new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "user-popup", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
                </section>
                <div id="user-popup"></div>
```

Controller Code:

```
 // GET: Users/Register
    public PartialViewResult Register()
    {
        return PartialView("_Register");
    }

    // POST: Users/Register
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "Username,Email,Password")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../Home/Index");
        }

        return Register();
    }
```

_Register code:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Username" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your controller, I believe that instead of just

```
return Register();
```

You'll need

```
return RedirectToAction("Register");
```

Comment: That just redirects me to same page as before but without the validation checks  e.g. 'The username field is required'

Comment: Because you're using ajax to get and popup the registration form, you'll lose this form whenever you do a page redirect. Two alternate methods would be to either do client side validation on your user viewmodel which would be the easiest. The other would be a using an ajax POST request, thus leaving your form on the screen.

Comment: Thank you! I used client side validation. Much appreciated.